# SQL Server 2008 Activity Monitor

Tags: sql-server-2008

While looking at the Activity Monitor in SQL Server, I notice that under the "Recent Expensive Queries" tab, the "Executions / min" column seems to balloon to a much higher number than it should be. 
What does this number actually mean? Is it literally how many times a SQL Query is performed in a minute, or does this number represent something else?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Expensive Query" you are analyzing might be using other subqueries (Let's say 10). Then could it be your "Executions / min" count is 10 times higher? Since an execution plan is recompiled for every subqueries?

Found this answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/6f147fb2-3cd8-46c7-9328-dd4f5ed2d076):

> The Execution/Min means the executions per minute for the query, the execution_count column in sys.dm_exec_query_stats indicates the number of times that the plan has been executed since it was last compiled. It is normal that the value of execution_count is not equal to the Execution/Min, since if the execution plan of your query recompiled or regenerated during execution, then the execution_count will be reset to 0 and recount. For instance, if this insert statement included into a transaction block, then the execution plan’s recompile might be caused by the other statement’s execution plan recompiled, so the execution_count will be reset to 0 and recount.
>
> Please refer to the below links for more detail information:
>
> > sys.dm_exec_query_stats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx 
> >     Activity Monitor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320(v=SQL.100).aspx
>
> Thanks, Weilin Qiao

Comment: Yeah I read that as well. If it includes sub queries it would be higher. But I just don't see how the executions / min could get to 17k when we may have 40 people on the website.

Comment: Well 17k/40 equals 425. Could they be clicking 10 times per minute. Each click (postback) executing 20 queries? And how many of these queries have subqueries? Have you tried calculating how many queries are being executed by the server on every postback (In the worst case scenario)?

Comment: I will dig through the queries that have the highest executions/min. So a number that high isn't necessarily worrying?